# Passing a variable to validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set-up a remote validation similar to the one in this example: 
[Example](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation)

My application has a twist however, my form elements are dynamically generated, therefore this tag:

```
[Remote("doesUserNameExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
```

is not set in stone, I need to vary the ErrorMessage for example and preferably vary the action. Is it possible, or would you suggest taking the long-way, meaning to implement the whole ajax validation on my own.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have a dynamic error message then you could return this as string from your validation action:

```
public ActionResult DoesUserNameExist(string username)
{
    if (Exists(uasername))
    {
        string errorMessage = "Some dynamic error message";
        return Json(errorMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And if you need even more flexibility such as invoking dynamic dynamic actions, then you're better of rolling your custom validation solution instead of relying on the built-in `Remote` attribute.

Comment: For our dynamic form, I chose to implement custom validation, it appears to be the most flexible way.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from RemoteAttribute and make it fetch the required values from a service or factory according to your own logic. Here is an example:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class MyRemoteAttribute : RemoteAttribute
    {
        public MyRemoteAttribute(Type type, string propertyName)
            : base(MyRemoteAttributeDataProvider.GetAttributeData(type,propertyName).Action,               MyRemoteAttributeDataProvider.GetAttributeData(type,propertyName).Controller)
        {
            var data = MyRemoteAttributeDataProvider.GetAttributeData(type,propertyName);
            base.ErrorMessage = data.ErrorMessage;
            base.HttpMethod = data.HttpMethod;
        }
    }

    public static class MyRemoteAttributeDataProvider
    {
        public static RemoteAttributeData GetAttributeData(Type type
           , string propertyName)
        {
            //this is where you are going to implement your logic im just implementing                 as an example
            //you can pass in a different type to get your values. For example you can  pass in a service to get required values.

            //property specific logic here, again im going to implement to make this
            //specification by example
           var attrData = new RemoteAttributeData();            
           if(propertyName == "MyOtherProperty")
           {
                attrData.Action = "MyOtherPropertyRelatedAction";
                attrData.Controller = "MyOtherPropertyRelatedController";
                attrData.ErrorMessage = "MyOtherPropertyRelated Error Message";
                attrData.HttpMethod = "POST";
           }            
           else 
           {            
                attrData.Action = "UserNameExists";
                attrData.Controller = "AccountController";
                attrData.ErrorMessage = "Some Error Message";
                attrData.HttpMethod = "POST";
           }
           return attrData;
        }
    }

    public class RemoteAttributeData
    {
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how you are supposed to use is:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [MyRemote(typeof(RegisterViewModel),"UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MyRemote(typeof(RegisterViewModel),"MyOtherProperty")]
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

As I also mentioned above at the commentary. You should specialize that provider according to your needs.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
I update the implementation based on your comment, so that it takes a property name and does some property name specific wiring.

Comment: There is a problem however, if I have several fields that need to be checked on the page, how can I tell the validator which field I am referring to?

Comment: @RealityDysfunction I updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: That's even better, however in my case this field needs to be a variable, because I never know which elements will be on the page. My model would look something like List<String> questions...

Comment: @RealityDysfunction Thats not important if your views are strongly typed. You just need to decorate the properties you wish to remotely check with this implementation of remote attribute. And also after noticing your selected answer, I couldn't help myself from reminding you; just to be clear, this is a custom validation solution, you can make it as dynamic as you can. You can pass in anything as property name (even a key) and return any controller-action-errormessage pair you wish. Even better, you can use strategy or command design patterns to make MyRemoteAttributeDataProvider better.

Comment: My problem is: "You just need to decorate the properties you wish to remotely check"...I cannot do this, because these properties are created on the fly, I never know when I need to decorate or not, and what exactly I need to check, database determines this.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction hmm.. so much for our attributes :) You should implement your own custom validation maybe derive those kinda entities from an abstract class and an abstract validate method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I learned a few things about these attributes.